# Limit objects in Realm Results by condition in order to observe result

Tags: swift, dynamic, realm, observers

I want to limit the objects in a realm results by some predicate in order to observe this results and update my UI based on its changes.

I have seen several solutions arguing that because objects in realm are lazy-loaded there is no need to limit the query. However I would like the query to constrain results by the limit in order for change notifications to fire when the objects constrained by the limit changes.

Let me give you an example:

Suppose I have a package object:

```
class Package: Object {

    @objc enum State: Int {
        case scheduled
        case delivered
    }

    @objc dynamic var state = State.scheduled
    @objc dynamic var deliveryDate = Date()
}
```

and I want to create a results of all packages that are scheduled AND ONLY the newest package that is delivered. How would I go about doing that? Is this even possible with a single Results that I could then observe for changes?

UPDATE:

Trying to be more clear about what I am looking for. Lets say I have the following packages in my realm:

```
Package1
  state: delivered
  deliveryDate: March 1st

Package2
  state: delivered
  deliveryDate: March 2nd

Package3
  state: delivered
  deliveryDate: March 3rd

Package4
  state: scheduled
  deliveryDate: March 4th

Package5
  state: scheduled
  deliveryDate: March 5th

Package6
  state: scheduled
  deliveryDate: March 6th
```

and let's say that these packages change state on a daily basis. So on March 3rd the data would look as above, but on March 4th Package4 would have changed state to 'delivered'. I then want a results that would reflect the following on those two days:

```
March 3rd:
  - Package3 (delivered)
  - Package4 (scheduled)
  - Package5 (scheduled)
  - Package6 (scheduled)

March 4th:
  - Package4 (delivered)
  - Package5 (scheduled)
  - Package6 (scheduled)
```

Comment: It appears like the conditions of the query change each day as the desired output is for that day forward. I updated my answer to address that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I going to attempt an answer but it may be off base.

The objective is to have a single realm result that can be observed for changes and also know what the newest delivery is.

Here's the code

```
self.packageResults = realm.objects(Package.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "delivered", ascending: false)
```

Then observe self.packageResults.

Whenever there's a change the observe closure will fire and deliver the results, sorted descending so the most current delivery will be 'at the top' i.e. index 0.

EDIT

Based on a comment and update to the question there was a question whether this answer provides a solution. Now there is a bit more data, just a slight modification produces the desired result (almost, keep reading)

```
self.packageResults = realm.objects(Package.self)
                           .filter("deliveryDate => 20190303")
                           .sorted(byKeyPath: "state", ascending: false)
```

then add an observer to self.packageResults. (note that I am using an Int for the timestamp to keep it simple)

To test, we use the data provided in the question with our observer code. The code prints the initial state of the data, and then prints the state after any delete, insert or modify.

```
func doObserve() {
     self.notificationToken = self.packageResults!.observe { (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in
         switch changes {
         case .initial:
             print("initial load complete")
             if let results = self.packageResults {
                 for p in results {
                     print(p.deliveryDate, p.state.rawValue)
                 }
             }
             break
         case .update(_, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):
             if let results = self.packageResults {
                 for p in results {
                     print(p.deliveryDate, p.state.rawValue)
                 }
             }
```

then we run the code and add the observer. This is the output

```
initial load complete
20190303 1
20190304 0
20190305 0
20190306 0
```

if we then change the package 20190304 to 'delivered' we get the following output

```
20190303 1
20190304 1
20190305 0
20190306 0
```

So we are getting the desired result. HOWEVER, according to the question, the conditions of the query change as the next query would be for dates 20190304 and after.

If the conditions of the output change, the conditions of the query would have to change as well. In this case the desired result is to display the most currently delivered package each day, so the query would need to be updated each day to reflect that date.

As a possible solution, change the Package object to include a watched property

```
class Package: Object {
    @objc enum State: Int {
        case scheduled
        case delivered
    }
    @objc dynamic var state = State.scheduled
    @objc dynamic var deliveryDate = 0
    @objc dynamic var watched = false
}
```

and update the query to only observe packages being watched, ignore ones not being watched (where watched = false)

```
self.packageResults = realm.objects(Package.self)
                           .filter("deliveryDate => 20190303 and watched == true")
                           .sorted(byKeyPath: "state", ascending: false)
```

Then, when you no longer need to know about an object, set it's watched property to false, and it will not be included in the results. Using the same process as above with this query, when changing 20190304 to delivered, we also change 20190303 watched property to false and the results are

```
 handle item delete, insert or mod
20190304 1
20190305 0
20190306 0
```

which appears to answer the question.

Comment: Hey Jay, thanks for taking the time to come with an answer. However it does not completely satisfy my requirements. I want all the 'scheduled' packages in the result and ONLY the newest 'delivered' package. Your solution would include all the delivered packages. I probably wasn't clear enough and have updated my original post.

Comment: @Darumar If you want just the first package, get the .first element from self.packageResults, that will always be the newest delivered package. *the most current delivery will be 'at the top' i.e. index 0.*

Comment: My issue is I observe the results to drive UI changes to a table view. That table view should show a list comprised of the most recent delivered package and all of the scheduled packages. If I manually have to build the list by picking from the results with i.e. results.first I cannot leverage the diff in Realms change notifications. This is why I want the results to reflect the complete query. Indeed I might end up with what you suggest and then having to write my own diff logic to drive my UI. I would just prefer to leverage Realm to do so, if possible.

Comment: @Darumar I think this answer will do what you want. The results will contain all of the packages scheduled for delivery and include the most recently delivered package - which is what you had asked in the original question. You can use the results as your tableView dataSource directly as the first item listed will always be the newest delivered package and the results are live-updated so if a newer package is delivered, the results will be updated. Perhaps I am not clear on what you're asking? Can you maybe update the question and I will try to come up with a solution.

Comment: thanks for your continued effort to help me out on this. I have updated my question to better explain what I am looking for. In your answer you sort byKeyPath 'delivered'. I am assuming this is a typo on your part, and that you mean 'deliveryDate'. If that is correct, it seems to me your answer would always give me the full list of packages sorted by delivery date. But what I want is only most recent of the packages that is in state 'delivered' and then all of the scheduled packages. Hope this clears up my question.

Comment: Hey @Jay thanks for taking your time to come up with a solution. You are right on spot, with a solution and its shortfall. I also considered adding the date to the query, but as you note, the date would have to change each day and thus the query updated. However since the app must be assumed to be non-terminated in the background and the query thus alive for the session across dates, it doesn't really work.

Comment: I have thought about it and arrived at the same conclusion as you, to have an additional flag on the model to indicate whether or not the package should be included in the results. If we do this we don't really need the date in the query as well, but we could have some separate logic modifying the "watched" state of the packages based on date changes. I have now decided to implement this on server side, such that the server decides which delivered packages to show and flag them accordingly. I still miss away to do this purely with realm, but seems not possible. Will accept your answer, thanks!